# Powershell commands for Distribution Lists in Public Folders

Tags: exchange-2007, powershell, public-folders, distribution-lists

How can I add and remove members to a distribution list in a public folder through PowerShell?

This is for Exchange 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching this, it looks like the answer is that it is not possible though Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "Marketing Managers" -Member adam@contoso.com
```

From here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995970.aspx

Pretty much the same for Removing:

but use Remove-DistributionGroupMember instead

Comment: I believe that is only for distribution groups using Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a mail-enabled public folder, you can use:

```
get-mailpublicfolder "foo" | set-mailpublicfolder -PrimarySmtpAddress "foo@example.com"
```